# Dining philosophers : Chandy-Misra approach : how does it avoid a deadlock?

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, dining-philosopher

I am trying it out , However a question :
In the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Chandy_.2F_Misra_solution) ,  the 3rd point of that algorithm says :

> When a philosopher with a fork receives a request message, he keeps the fork if it is clean, but gives it up when it is dirty. If he sends the fork over, he cleans the fork before doing so

I'm trying to understand why this does not lead to a deadlock ? if one philosopher has one clean fork , and waits to get another clean fork from a neighboring diner/philosopher , who in turn is waiting for a fork as well , this can cumulate to a deadlock right ? one philosopher always waiting for a fork from the other ?

ps: I'm new to threads and concurrency , took this up as a learning project.

Edit : actual place where forks are given , posting this to ask if forks should be mutable or not.
pLeft , pRight are left and right philosophers , fLeft and fRight are left and right forks.

```
private Fork giveFork(Philosopher diner) {
        Fork forkToGive;

        if (this.pLeft.equals(diner)) {
            // give left fork to left philosopher
            if (this.fLeft.isClean)
                forkToGive = null; // don't give
            else {
                forkToGive = new Fork(this.fLeft.id, true); // give the fork
            }

        } else if (diner.pRight.equals(this)) {
            // give right fork to right philosopher
            if (this.fRight.isClean)
                forkToGive = null;
            else {
                forkToGive = new Fork(this.fRight.id, true);
            }
        } else {
            // default value , i'm not yet sure if this code
            // can be theoretically reached
            forkToGive = null;
        }

        return forkToGive;

    }
```

I havent figured out where to synchronize it , But i do feel synchronization is still needed.  Like when two diners , say the first and the 3rd ask the 2nd philosopher for a fork.

Comment: Description says that philosopher gives fork up if it's dirty and at the start all forks are dirty.

Comment: True , but i dont understand how to initialize "all" the forks ? Do i keep a collection of forks ? and change them to clean/dirty with time ? I'm trying to have as much immutability i can , so i decided against keeping a collection of mutable forks , and create and give new clean forks when required.

Comment: forks _are_ shared resource and must be mutable (otherwise, whole protocol unneeded, as each philosopher can always get clean pair of forks). Generally, all fancy sync protocols needed to manage mutable data shared across processes/threads, if your data is immutable (purely functional), you not need to worry about sync.

Comment: From the pov of the philosopher who is giving the dirty fork , He has to clean it first , now lets say i create a copy of the dirty fork , only making it clean , and replace the dirty one with the new clean one , there is still one fork , and immutability too..

Comment: There's no need to synchronize anything if you can create new instances of resources. Only when resources are limited (like filespace on a disk or network connections or memory) there's need for synchronization (cooperation) of actors.

Comment: I'v edited my post to add some code , and why i feel synchronization is still needed. If you could take a look would be great.

Comment: Assuming `giveFork()` is executed by philosopher which provides fork, you will need  synchronization to return generated fork to requester (like, via `wait()/notifyAll()`). But this code is more complex then necessary because of fork creation. Actually, there's no need to have dedicated `Fork` class, all you need is array `ForkState forks[philosophersNr]`, and have your parties synchronize on it.

Answer (score 5):

The source you cite explains it:

> However, if the system is initialized to a perfectly symmetric state,
>   like all philosophers holding their left side forks, then the graph is
>   cyclic at the outset, and their solution cannot prevent a deadlock.
>   Initializing the system so that philosophers with lower IDs have dirty
>   forks ensures the graph is initially acyclic.

So, you need to initialise the system to an asymmetric state,
and the set of rules are designed not to leave the desired (non-deadlock state).

Comment: Hey thanks for mentioning that part. I missed it . But i dontreally understand how to keep my forks : mutable or not. can you help ?

Comment: both should work as at any single point a fork has only one owner: the original algorithm is designed for a distributed environment so it helps to think in terms of message passing (so every time you pass a fork, you create and send a new message)